# JSON Parse Error on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, parsing

I'm using a jscript to retrieve JSON data from Flickr. Works 100% in every browsers except IE.
I'm using the jquery each function that calls this specific function for IE:

```
//some code
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {    
  var xdr;  
  var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=" + apiKey + "&photoset_id=" + set + "&extras=url_sq&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";  
  xdr = new XDomainRequest();
  if (xdr) {  
    xdr.open("get", url);  
    xdr.send();   
    var data = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);
    //some jquery stuff
  }
}
```

In IE the function return's a syntax error in the **var data = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);** but the error is random, it retrieves a random number of photos before showing the error..

I've checked all the variables involved and everything is returning OK.

I'm using the json2.js

UPDATE:

JSON possible results:

```
{
    "photoset": {
        "id": "72157627083924637",
        "primary": "5943107169",
        "owner": "63570294@N03",
        "ownername": "motorespt.com",
        "photo": [
            {
                "id": "5943107169",
                "secret": "e6099e3936",
                "server": "6029",
                "farm": 7,
                "title": "Peugeot 206",
                "isprimary": "0",
                "url_sq": "http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6029/5943107169_e6099e3936_s.jpg",
                "height_sq": 75,
                "width_sq": 75
            }
        ],
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 500,
        "perpage": 500,
        "pages": 1,
        "total": "1"
    },
    "stat": "ok"
}
```

or

```
{"stat":"fail", "code":1, "message":"Photoset not found"}
```

UPDATE:
 thanks to all the help i was able to find the error and make a function compatible with IE 7+, Firefox, Chrome, etc..

```
function flickr_test(){
  var apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
    data: {
        method: 'flickr.test.echo',
        api_key: apiKey, 
        format: 'json',
        test: 'test string',
        jsoncallback: 'jsonFlickrApi'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
}
function jsonFlickrApi(response){
  console.log(response.stat);
}
```

P.S.: the 'test' var is string that i wanted to pass to the callback function

Comment: Could add some example json file?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? (`$.browser.msie`) If so, why not use it for the Ajax request too?

Comment: I use jQuery for the Ajax request for browsers like chrome and firefox, i've tried to use it for IE, but with no success

Comment: @João: It is mor likely that jQuery will work than your custom solution.

Comment: I've updated the jQuery Ajax request (that currently doesn't work on IE browsers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parsing JSON on IE 8 and below have issues. It fails to identify JSON functions.

Download the file https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js
Include it in your application and it should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a different method when using different browsers:

choose eval in IE6, 7 
choose native JSON in IE8 
choose new Function in Firefox2, 3 
choose eval in Safari4 
eval has the same performance as new Function on the whole when you use the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the file https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js 
you'll have this error:
"parsing string: Line: 191 Error: Object doesn't support this property or method".
the property or method is valueOf().

I use the solution suggested in [JSON2 Error / Conflict with another script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298324/json2-error-conflict-with-another-script)

*return ((typeof this.valueOf === 'function') ? this.valueOf(): this.toString());*
instead of
*return this.valueOf();*