# Redirect from Angular JS not working for URL with hash '#'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Background of how I am initializing my AngularJS app is here : 
[SCRIPT5022: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! and redirecting to index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276261/script5022-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-and-redirecting-to-index)

**Summery Problem**

When I do a *window.location = $scope.myReturnUrl* and if the return URL contains a **"#"**, instead of reloading the page, AngularJS captures the url change and it goes to *.otherwise* part of rout provider setting, and  Angular App is loaded again. But, I am expecting it to redirect to specified URL.

**Brief of how I am doing this:**

I am loading my AngularJS app inside a Bootstrap Modal, this is how I initialize

```
var markup = '<div id="ng-app" ng-app="myapp" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"><div ng-controller="MyAppAppCtrl"><div ng-view></div></div></div>';
jQuery('#works-modal').html(markup);
angular.bootstrap(jQuery('#ng-app'), ['myapp']);   
jQuery('#works-modal').modal('show');
```

in my app.js, html5mode is set to false for all modules :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false)
```

So, when my app is initialized, the url look something like :

http://my-site.uk/user/dashboard.html#/mywork/find/id/9780273651

Now, there is a cancel button on Modal dialog, click on which I am trapping through ng-click, and when clicked, it simply do a redirection something like

```
window.location = $rootScope.returnToUrl;
```

now, in my case, return url contains id of the link that was clicked, so that browser can scroll to particular section, the return url is :

```
http://my-site.uk/user/dashboard.html#my-work1
```

**my rout provider config**

```
$routeProvider.
        when('/mywork/find/:id', {
          templateUrl: '/mywork/partials/find/find.html',
          controller: WorkCtrl
        }).
        when('/mywork/find/review/submit/:id', {
          templateUrl: '/mywork/partials/review.html',
          controller: ReviewCtrl
        }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/mywork/find/id/'+id
      });
```

**Problem**

Now, when I am trying to redirect to : http://my-site.uk/user/dashboard.html#my-work1
instead of reloading page and scrolling to designated #ID, AngularJS is capturing the URL change and reloading the app instead. this happens because, AngularJS captures the url change and it goes to *.otherwise* part of rout provider setting, and  Angular App is loaded again. But, I am expecting it to redirect to specified URL.

I am use html5mode(true) due to historic reason (mentioned in this thread : [SCRIPT5022: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! and redirecting to index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276261/script5022-10-digest-iterations-reached-aborting-and-redirecting-to-index))

I don't want to remove the # from my return url because it will break the workflow. Any suggestion how to overcome this?

Thanks,

Ravish

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you want http://my-site.uk/user/dashboard.html#my-work1 to redirect you to dashboard.html and scroll to the element with `id="my-work1"`.

You might want to take a look at the `$anchorScroll`(http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$anchorScroll) service. I'm not sure how it works exactly as I've never needed to use it, but I know it solves problems such as yours.

Comment: there is once problem though, what if I am trying to a page that is not an "AngularJS" App? I mean, I do want to scroll to that particular section, but, that whole page is not AngularJS. I am using `window.location = MY_REDIRECT_URL` to redirect to some page. the redirect url happens to contain a **#**, but, there should be a way to 'tell' AngularJS, that do not listen to /^these_urls[-]*/i, ?

Comment: I've resolved my problem by using a work around, I'll answer my question with details. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

in your URL (`http://my-site.uk/user/dashboard.html#my-work1`) try pass 'my-work1'as a parameter in routeProvider like `http://my-site.uk/user/dashboard.html/my-work1`.

example:

```
when('/my/route/:param', {
    templateUrl: '/mywork/partials/param.html',
    controller: WorkCtrl
})
```

in your controller, get this parameter with $routeParams.

```
var myParam = $routeParams.param
$location.hash(myParam)//set anchor
$anchorScroll()//do scroll
```

I hope this solve your problem

Comment: @ops-rio there is once problem though, what if I am trying to a page that is not an "AngularJS" App? I mean, I do want to scroll to that particular section, but, that whole page is not AngularJS. I am using `window.location = MY_REDIRECT_URL` to redirect to some page. the redirect url happens to contain a **#**, but, there should be a way to 'tell' AngularJS, that do not listen to /^these_urls[-]*/i, ?

Comment: @RavishTiwari could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: let me see if I can create one

Comment: @ops-rio I've resolved my problem by using a work around, I'll answer my question with details. thanks for your answer